# HTML not validating

Tags: html

My HTML document is not validating. Every validator I've tried says there is one more `<p>` tag . I've checked it and there is the same amount of p's and /p's. Is it possible that online validators are wrong?

Whole code: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bsvyxzoc/)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pl">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Moje hobby</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Strona stworzona na potrzeby projektu." />
    <meta name="keywords" content="filmy, kino, seriale, projekt" />
    <meta name="author" content="Jakub Krzyżyński" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="Style.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
```

Comment: Some tell you the line number.

Comment: I tried validating using this https://www.onlinewebcheck.com and it said you have an extra <ul>

Comment: Is it possible? Everything is. Is it likely? No.

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: I wanted to know how to make my document validate, @luka answered my question ;)

Comment: in the future, please include relevant code in the question itself. Not an external link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because the `ul` (unordered list) elements are not actually allowed inside `p` elements.

As you can see, the below snippet is from your code (from the fiddle). It looks fine (as in all tags are closed) although there is an `ul` inside the `p` tag, which technically isn't allowed. This is why you are getting the errors when validating

[`p`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) elements can only contain **phrasing** content, and because `ul` elements are **flow** content, they cannot be placed inside a `p` element.

```html
<p>
  Film to bardzo obszerna dziedzina i można ją podzielić na wiele sposobów. Podstawowy i najbardziej popularny z nich to podział na rodzaje:
  <ul>
    <li>film fabularny – aktorski film fikcji,</li>
    <li>film animowany – tworzony za pomocą klasycznych technik poklatkowych – rysunkowych lub przestrzennych lub najnowszych technik komputerowych – animacji 3D,</li>
    <li>film dokumentalny – film o treści niefikcyjnej, dokumentujący rzeczywistość,</li>
    <li>film oświatowy – dla celów dydaktyczno-instruktażowych,</li>
    <li>film propagandowy – dla celów jakich w danym momencie wymaga propaganda</li>
  </ul>
</p>
```

From the W3 specifications:

> A `p` element's end tag may be omitted if the `p` element is immediately followed by an `address`, `article`, `aside`, `blockquote`, `div`, `dl`, `fieldset`, `footer`, `form`, `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h5`, `h6`, `header`, `hgroup`, `hr`, `main`, `nav`, `ol`, `p`, `pre`, `section`, `table`, or **`ul`**, element, or if there is no more content in the parent element and the parent element is not an `a` element.

Comment: No problem! You can read more about the semantics here - https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element And if my answer solved your problem, please accept it :)

Comment: Good answer and explanation!  Best I've seen all day.

Comment: Huh. I'm sure I've done this before and no compiler has ever yelled at me.